# How do I use code generated from WSDL2OBJC 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, web-services, soap

hi everyone  i am new to iphone development and started with some sample application.

In sample application i am using webservices..i went through this tutorial http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions and understood about wsdl2objc..

but this tutorial is too short so can anyone suggest similar like tutorial or examples  so tat is still more clear...

thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All depends on your web service class name etc as wsdl2objc makes up alot of your NSObjects and methods based upon this, however, 
suggesting that you are using soap 1.2 bindings and your web service was called 'SimpleService', the following would call a web method named 'MobileTestService and return back the integer value from the xml generated.

```
-(NSString *)returnThatStringFromWebServiceResult {


SimpleServiceSoap12Binding * binding = [SimpleService SimpleServiceSoap12Binding];
binding.logXMLInOut = YES; // shows all in the console log.
SimpleService_concat * testParams = [[SimpleService_concat new]autorelease];
testParams.s1 = someTextField.text; // parameters all become properties of this testParams object
testParams.s2 = anotherTextField.text;
SimpleServiceSoap12BindingResponse * response= [binding SimpleService_concatUsingParameters:testParams];
[response self]; // removes compile error

NSArray * responseBodyParts = response.bodyParts;
NSError * responseError = response.error;

if (responseError!=NULL) {
    return @"";  // if error from ws use [responeError code]; for http err code


}

for (id bodyPart in responseBodyParts)
{
    if ([bodyPart isKindOfClass:[SimpleService_concat_Response class]]) 
    {
        SimpleService_concatResponse* body = (SimpleService_concatResponse*) bodyPart;
        return body.SimpleService_concatResult; // if you are returning a string from your WS then this value will be a string, 

    }

}
}
```

Comment: thank u for ur response...My webservice class name is SimpleService_concat where i need to concat two strings "s1" and "s2",as there are too many methods i am confused which method wat is there as i am new to iphone so i am not gud at coding...class is simpleservice_concat and two strings s1 and s2...file is simpleservice.h/.m so can u help me further..i am using a tetfield and button to display it on UI in textfield..so plz suggest me how to do...

Comment: first are you writing a web service in c#? ,if so, can you let me know  the class name of the web service not the web method name?

Comment: i am writing in objective-c....class is of NSobject and class name is simpleservice

Comment: i hope you are writing in objective c for iphone, i meant your web service. the one you will be sending soap requests to?

Comment: ya iam writing in objective-c for iphone...ya we have use soap protocols to call services....how to retrive tat strings?as there r so many methods so i am getting confused....

Comment: check my modded answer, this returns a string from the webservice and takes two string in as parameters to your web method.

Comment: What if "body.SimpleService_concatResult" not a simple String, but a collection? How would I get it? @crazy2431, burrows111.

Comment: @surlac a collection would become an array ... so your '_concatResult' object would be an array. You can then iterate over the array of objects at your own will. does that make sense?