# how to get the value which is returned from the web service using soap in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, soap

how to get the  value which is returned from the web service using soap in iphone

this is my SOAP response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <fnPartyQuestionsPathResponse xmlns="http://QIA/">
      <fnPartyQuestionsPathResult>string</fnPartyQuestionsPathResult>
    </fnPartyQuestionsPathResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: show me your response of webservice?

Comment: @RakeshBhatt  for soap response  please see my edited Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a Good Tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/) for calling SOAP Services from iPhone.

Comment: thanx for ur reply  ,,i know calling the web service,, but i am not getting how to get the value which is being returned from web service(suppose a string value is returned from web service)

Comment: Set Connection Delegate to self > In Connection Delegate Methods there is didRecieveData method, which gives you NSData, > receive this NSData, Parse this variable using any Parser (e.g NSXMLParser) like we do in REST XML API.

Answer (score 0):

WSDL2OBJC - does all the work for you, look here :>[CLICK ME](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/)

I have supported it for a while, a good example how to use it was answered on this question - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533920/how-do-i-use-code-generated-from-wsdl2objc/6579302#comment-7762394)

Comment: thanx for ur reply ,,what is  SimpleServiceSoap12Binding in that code,, its showing error

Comment: SimpleService is the web service class name and the Soap12binding is to use soap 1.2 ass the biding, all the objects and method names are generated with a name based upon your class name and web method names.